# Indefinite integral: $\int \frac{\log x}{ x + 4x \log^2 x} dx$

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate value of the following integral
 $$\int\frac{\log x} {x + 4x \log^2 x} dx$$
in the most simple way?

Answer (score 4):

Factor out the x:

$$\int{(\log x) \over x(1 + 4 \log^2 x)} dx$$
Let $u = \log x$

So, $du = \frac{1}{x}$
$$\int \frac{u}{1 + 4u^2} du$$
This is now a simple integral:

$$\int \frac{u}{1 + 4u^2} du = \frac{1}{8}\ln|1 + 4u^2|+ C = \frac{1}{8}\ln|1 + 4\log^2x|+ C$$

Answer (score 1):

We could do it in one step, but two steps may be more natural. Let $u=\log x$. Now we want to integrate $\frac{u}{1+4u^2}$. Let $v=1+4u^2$.

The one step way is to let $w=1+4\log^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int{(\log x) \over (x + 4x \log^2 x)} dx=\int{(\log x) \over x(1 + 4 \log^2 x)} dx=$
$\int{(\log x) \over (1 + 4 \log^2 x)} d(\log x)=\frac{1}{2}\int {d(\log x)^2 \over (1 + 4 \log^2 x)}=\frac{1}{8}\int{d(1+4\log^2x) \over (1+4\log^2x)}=\frac{1}{8}\log (1+4\log^2x)+C$